# How do i fill or connect these vertices to create a face?

Tags: vertices, faces

How do i connect these vertices? i've already tried using the Fill tool and also merging but none of them work
[image]

[image: Using Fill]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try this kind of topology:

[image]

Comment: look at all those ngons.  ;)

Comment: ngons are not always a problem  ;)  plus I was just showing the way

Comment: More like hinting at the way than showing it, I think. ;)

Comment: sure, but it would be very long to do the whole thing

Comment: about 6 paragraphs, with a few bullet points, I think.  About 15 minutes of typing, but what would I know?

Comment: you should be lazier, like I am  ^^

Comment: When you're lazy you get upvoted. When I'm lazy I get downvoted. There's just no justice ;)

Comment: sorry for that, being lazy is very difficult by the way, and I'm also downvoted sometimes!!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129720/discussion-between-marty-fouts-and-moonboots).